# Como montar um sistema de includes com o $_GET

Tags: php

Queria deixar meu site mais leve, ele tem 7 páginas como incluir todas essas páginas na home com a URL ficando assim `?pagina=contato` e assim pra todas as páginas

Comment: Isso me parece ferir diretamente o princípio da atomicidade do código e, assim, não ser uma boa solução. Qual a real necessidade de colocar em um arquivo só toda a lógica da aplicação?

Comment: deixar os códigos mais limpos e creio que mais leve

Answer (score 4):

Faz assim amigo

```
    <?php
$pagina = $_GET['pagina'];

   if($pagina == "contato"){
        include_once("Pages/contato.php");
   }elseif($pagina == "outra"){
       include_once("Pages/outra.php");
}
   ?>
```

Comment: Ai no caso no menu a URL ficaria assim `<a href="home.php?pagina=contato">Contato</a>`?

Comment: Exatamente, aí quando a página for igual a contatos ele vai chamar sua página contatos

Comment: Me diz mais uma coisa, esse sistema funciona com ID? exemplo `<a href="home.php?pagina=capítulos?id_livro=Genesis">Livros</a>`

Comment: @mayron2017 faz um novo If no id_livro e no próximo Array utiliza & ao invés de ?

Comment: <a href="home.php?pagina=capitulo&id_livro=genesis>Livro</a>

Comment: Aí pelo que entendi dentro de capítulo terá algo escrito que vc quer usar essa tag Gênesis basta vc receber a variável get do id_livro na página capítulo...

Comment: Como assim, não intenso muito bem

Comment: Ex: <a href="home.php?pagina=capitulo&id_livro=genesis>Livro</a> a variável página vc paga na sua homepage trabalha o else/If ... Porém a id_livro , você pega ela na sua página capitulo.php

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66691/discussion-between-mayron2017-and-carlos-da-silva).

Answer (score 0):

é assim que faço meu código PHP:

```
<?php  
$url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : 'home';

if(file_exists('pages/'.$url.'.php')){
    include('pages/'.$url.'.php');
}else{
    include('pages/home.php');
}
?>
```

para usar esse método é necessário criar um arquivo .htaccess na raiz do seu site com esses dados:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

Options -Indexes
```

Você deve tamber criar uma constante no seu config.php para seu diretório raiz, eu coloco "INCLUDE_PATH", ficaria assim:

```
define("INCLUDE_PATH", "linkdoseusite.com/")
```

Com isso, basta você criar os links dessa maneira no html:

```
<a href="<?=INCLUDE_PATH?>meulink">carrinho</a>
```

Dessa maneira quando alguém clicar em um link no seu site, o PHP fará um $_GET no link e caso haja um arquivo com o mesmo nome do link ele irar dar um include daquele arquivo na sua página.
Espero que fique compreensivel!